# Is nutrient absorption different in Hypersensitive I patients?

Tags: diet, allergies, eggs, hypersensitivity

I am thinking how the nutrient absorption differs between between patients with allergies (Hypersensitivity I) and those not.

The current guideline about number of eggs in diet is one daily regularly.
My professor says that 1-4 eggs daily can be also ok because cholesterol is inhibited.

However, I am thinking if we have Hypersensitive (allergic) person, what the recommendation should be then.
My hypothesis says that more cholesterol would be absorbed and less inhibited.
However, I cannot find any evidence for this hypothesis.

Hypersensitive response is fast. 
I am interested in many responses during long term.

**How does nutrient absorption differ in hypersensitive patient and normal patient?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absorption is itself not different, but the rate of absorbed substances is different because of greater amounts of proteins in the allergic lymphatic circulation. 
So less capacity stays for circulation of nutrients and so less absorption in time.